# I can't get past the moonshot on True Vault Hunter Mode

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm trying to play True Vault Hunter mode using Handsome Jack.

Once I got moonshot, I never got the cut scene and I can't open the door to the Wastes. I also can't see my gun or HUD and can only use my action skill.

I have already tried resetting and playing with friends. I join their game, but they end up in the box with me.

UPDATE: I have beaten the game with Athena and now she is also stuck in the box. I believe this is a really bad game breaking glitch.

UPDATE 2: I thought of going into regular vault hunter mode, strangely I did not think of that before, and still I end up in the box.

LAST UPDATE: it seems that nothing will help, even playing online or with another's disk or even another's XBOX 360.

Comment: This sounds more like your game bugged out than it not letting you progress for missing a requirement.

Comment: When you say you've tried resetting, have you started the game over from the beginning, when Claptrap welcomes you to the moon base? You still end up stuck in the box?

Comment: Have you tried dropping and re-accepting the quest?

Comment: How exactly do you do that on Xbox 360?

Comment: Man, Athena is in the box too? That's crazy. Have you reset the system cache on your Xbox?

Comment: Yes, I actually believe I have tried EVERYTHING @DCShannon

Comment: @LandonPoling a few other suggestions would be to revert updates and then try playing offline, try downloading a save form the internet and see if it gets stuck there too, or try to kill yourself in there (very possible to do on NG+ with your athena)

Comment: I have tried grenades and I seem invincible whilst in the box and all my updates can't be removed on my Xbox

Comment: @LandonPoling I guess it's possible that your disc or install is corrupt, and it can't read the specific piece of data it needs to open that door. Not sure why that would affect your friends if you join *their* game, though. Can't tell for sure if you've re-installed it from what you've written already (although that would be part of EVERYTHING). Could maybe try re-installing, or using someone else's disc or Xbox.

Comment: Did you ever contact Gearbox technical support about this?

Comment: Have no working phone and the only time I get internet is at school...(Which blocks nearly every gaming website and gmail.) so no contact has been made. That's why I'm on this website.